# How can i use args.length control in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to develop an app using twitter4j and fabric. There is example which i can call Listing followers id but i don't know how i can use arg.length in android. Android studio can not resolve args argument. What can i use instead of it for this code ?

```
try {
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                long cursor = -1;
                IDs ids;

                System.out.println("Listing followers's ids.");
                do {
                    if (0 < args.length) {
                        ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs(args[0], cursor);
                    } else {
                        ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs(cursor);
                    }
                    for (long id : ids.getIDs()) {
                        System.out.println(id);
                    }
                } while ((cursor = ids.getNextCursor()) != 0);
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (TwitterException te) {
                te.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Failed to get followers' ids: " + te.getMessage());
                System.exit(-1);
            }
```

Comment: It looks like you've copied code from a method with a varargs parameter. `args` is most likely defined in that method's signature. Check your example again.

Comment: yes you are right i copied from example. I understood what code is doing. But i dont know what i will use instead of args in android.

Comment: We'd need to see the example you're following.

Comment: You can see at following link. Thanks for your attention.

https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/friendsandfollowers/GetFollowersIDs.java

Comment: It appears you just need to replace `args[0]` with a String for the screen name. (Your example is for straight Java, and `args` represent command line arguments, which an Android app won't have.)

Comment: Oh, you'll have to change your `if` statement, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. At twitter4j documentation(http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/FriendsFollowersResources.html) getFollowersIDs is overloaded.
So we can use long userId instead of args.

```
try {
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                long cursor = -1;
                IDs ids;

                System.out.println("Listing followers's ids.");
                do {
                    if (0 < userId) {
                        ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs(userId, cursor);
                    } else {
                        ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs(cursor);
                    }
                    for (long id : ids.getIDs()) {
                        System.out.println(id);
                    }
                } while ((cursor = ids.getNextCursor()) != 0);
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (TwitterException te) {
                te.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Failed to get followers' ids: " + te.getMessage());
                System.exit(-1);
            }
```